# Pan/Zoom to specific group ID/getBBox() with d3.behavior.zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I'm attempting to make an interactive pan/zoom SVG floorplan/map using the `d3.behavior.zoom()` functionality. I have based my code loosely on [Zoom to Bounding Box II](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/9656675).

I am asynchronously loading a svg via `$.get()` then using a `button.on('click')` handler to get the `.getBBox()` of a specific `<g>` by element ID, `#g-1101` (represented as a red circle on the svg). I then would like to center the viewport of the svg to the middle of `#g-1101`'s bounding box.

As a cursory try I was just trying to translate the top-level `svg > g` by using `g#1101`'s `.getBBox().x && .getBBox().y`. It seems to me my math is off.

I've tried incorporating the `(svg.node().getBBox().width / 2) - scale * g.getBBox().x)` to center the middle point of the bounding box to viewport but it's translation is not even in the ballpark.

**Code**

```
(function(){

 var svg, g; $.get('http://layersofcomplexity.com/__fp.svg', function(svg){
   $('body').append($(svg));
   init();
  },'text');

  function init() {

    console.log('init');

   svg = d3.select('svg');
   g = d3.select('svg > g');

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

    $('.pan').on('click', function(){
//       var id = '#g-1011';
      var scale = 4;
      var bbox = $('#g-1101')[0].getBBox(); 
//       d3.select(id).node().getBBox();
      var x = bbox.x;
      var y = bbox.y;
      // var scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
      // var translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
      var width = svg.node().getBBox().width;
      var height = svg.node().getBBox().height;
      var translate = [-scale*x,-scale*y];
      g.transition().duration(750) .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
    });

  }

  function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

})();
```

*-- EDIT JSBin was broken --*

What am I missing? [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kihete/).

Comment: Not clear the fiddle is zooming an panning is there something in particular you are looking here...the question is not clear..

Comment: I was on a friends computer when I uploaded the SVG and made the JSBin. Apparently it got all messed up, so I just fixed it. It should be working now. Ideally I would be able to hit the `Pan` button and pan/zoom to `g#g-1101`

Comment: Nothing happens on the JSBin. Intended?

Answer (score 1):

One small change in your code to center the marked in red `g#g-1101`

```
  var bbox = $('#g-1101')[0].getBBox(); 


  var x = bbox.x-((bbox.width));
  var y = bbox.y-((bbox.height));
  //scale should be 1 less
  var translate = [-(x*(scale-1)),-(y*(scale-1))];
```

working code [here](http://jsbin.com/sisubaraha/1/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this helps